# Separate a part of nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "align": "center",
   "part": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "transfer",
      "bunch": [
         {
            "part": {
               "id": "1"
            }
         },
         {
            "line": {
               "data": {
                  "reference": "transferRtgs"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "rcp": [
      {
         "id": "100",
         "name": "cardBalance",
         "bunch": [
            {
               "part": {
                  "id": "1"
               }
            },
            {
               "line": {
                  "data": {
                     "reference": "source",
                     "label": "sourceLabel"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "part": {
                  "id": "2"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id": "101",
         "name": "creditBalance",
         "bunch": [
            {
               "part": {
                  "id": "1"
               }
            },
            {
               "line": {
                  "data": {
                     "reference": "creditAmount"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "part": {
                  "id": "2"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I separate a part of nested JSON object and copy it into another JSON object?

I want just this part of my JSON:

```
{
   "id": "101",
   "name": "creditBalance",
   "bunch": [
      {
         "part": {
            "id": "1"
         }
      },
      {
         "line": {
            "data": {
               "reference": "creditAmount"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "part": {
            "id": "2"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Actually I want to write a method that when I pass an id to it, it finds that corresponding rcp key and returns that JSON object, I don't know how to do it, Could anybody give me an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `filter` for your JSON data

```
function objectFilter(id){
   const selecJson = json.rcp.filter(el => el.id == id)
   return selecJson;
}
```

then call your function

`objectFilter(id);`